# Maximum size of metadata in Azure Blob Store

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using the Azure blob's metadata information mechanism mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-properties-metadata) to save some information in the blob store, and later retrieve information from it.

My questions are mainly related to performance and maintenance concerns.

1. Is there any upper limit on the size of this metadata? What is the
   maximum number of keys I can store ?
2. Does it expire after a certain date?
3. Is there any chance of losing data that is stored in the blob
   metadata

If yes, I would go ahead, and write these to a database, from the service I am writing. However, ideally, I would like to use the blob's metadata feature, which is very useful, and well thought out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Setting-and-Retrieving-Properties-and-Metadata-for-Blob-Resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN

The size of the metadata cannot exceed 8 KB altogether. This means keys, values, semicolons, everything. There is no explicit limitation for the number of keys themselves, but all of them (with the actual values and other characters) must fit into the 8 KB limit.

As for the expiration, I don't think so. At least the documentation doesn't mention it. I guess if expiration was an issue, it would be important enough to be mentioned in the documentation :)

As for losing the metadata: metadata is stored along the blob, so if you lose the blob you lose the metadata (like the datacenter explodes and you didn't have the appropriate replication for your account). Other than that, I don't think it can just disappear. The documentation also states that partial updates are not possible, so it is either updated fully or not, you can't lose half of your updates.